# Can I restart my python code using a try/except?

Tags: python, error-handling, try-catch, try-except

I have a program where I am going to the reddit.com website and grabbing an html element from it. however, about 1/10th of the time, the old reddit website shows up, and I have to restart the program. Is there any shorter way to handle this error (basically restart from the top again)? I couldn't seem to figure it out with a try/except.

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\jacka\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')

browser.get("https://www.reddit.com/")

# grabs the html tag for the subreddit name
elem = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("a[data-click-id='subreddit']")

#in the case that old reddit loads, it restarts the browser.
if len(elem) == 0:
    browser.close()

    browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\jacka\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')

    browser.get("https://www.reddit.com/")

    # grabs the html tag for the subreddit name
    elem = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("a[data-click-id='subreddit']")
```

Comment: Envelope everything in a while loop, and break only on success.

Comment: `if len(elem) == 0:` -> `if not elem:` (more beautiful in the Python sense)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved thanks to @HSK. I put the code in a `while` loop that ran until it got the right version of reddit.

```
#had to initalize elem so the loop would run
elem = ""
while len(elem) == 0:
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\jacka\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')

    browser.get("https://www.reddit.com/")

    # grabs the html tag for the subreddit name
    elem = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("a[data-click-id='subreddit']")
```

Answer (score 1):

Like @HSK has mentioned in the comment, you can use an infinite `while` loop to keep trying until you get what you want without an exception. Do add a `finally` clause to close the `browser` handle before leaving.

```
while True:
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\jacka\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')
    try:
        browser.get("https://www.reddit.com/")
        elem = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("a[data-click-id='subreddit']")
        break
    except Exception:
        pass
    finally:
        browser.close()
```